# Can't launch activity only once - Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?

Tags: android-espresso

I need to launch activity **only once** before all tests.
So I use annotation `@BeforeClass`  for this.

Here Espresso's test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class JsonViewActivityTest {

    companion object {
        init {
            // things that may need to be setup before companion class member variables are instantiated
        }

        @get:Rule
var jsonViewIntentsTestRule = IntentsTestRule(JsonViewActivity::class.java, false, false)

        private val instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
        private val context = instrumentation.getContext()
        private val targetContext = instrumentation.getTargetContext()
        private val intent = Intent(targetContext, JsonViewActivity::class.java)

        @BeforeClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun beforAll() {
            Intent(targetContext, JsonViewActivity::class.java)
            val bundle = Bundle()
            val inputStream = context.assets.open(StubUtil.TradersStub.ONE_TRADER_HAS_WALLETS.stubName)
            val content = inputStream.readBytes().toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            val jsonArray = GsonUtil.gson.fromJson(content, JsonArray::class.java)
            val jsonTrader = jsonArray.get(0)
            val trader = GsonUtil.gson.fromJson(jsonTrader, Trader::class.java)
            val wallet = trader.wallets[0]
            bundle.putString(JsonViewActivity.WALLET_JSON, GsonUtil.gson.toJson(wallet))
            intent.putExtras(bundle)

            jsonViewIntentsTestRule.launchActivity(intent)
        }

        @AfterClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun afterAll() {
            jsonViewIntentsTestRule.finishActivity()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun toolBar_height() {
        onView(withId(R.id.toolBar))
                .check(ViewAssertions.matches(CustomMatchers.withHeightResId(R.dimen.tool_bar_height)))
    }
}
```

But test `toolBar_height` is fail with message:

```
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.waitForAtLeastOneActivityToBeResumed(RootViewPicker.java:169)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.RootViewPicker.get(RootViewPicker.java:83)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule.java:77)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.provideRootView(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:35)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:24)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.get(ViewInteractionModule_ProvideRootViewFactory.java:10)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.ViewFinderImpl.getView(ViewFinderImpl.java:62)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:276)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:268)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: is `beforAll` misspelled?

Comment: I'm seeing exactly what you're seeing.  I can start an activity before any test are run, but when the first test runs, that started activity is closed; I can also see that the activities view window is gone.  Test that don't involve the activity work perfect fine but tests that evolve the activity fail. The only way I've been able to  run multiple tests against the same activity is by adding the @Before and starting the activity for each test.  When a test completes the activity goes away and we start it again for the next test.  That's of course what we were trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I traced AndroidJUnit4 code till I found out what's happening.  The quick answer is that all open Activity's are automagically "finished" before each test begins.  This is done in android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.  That class contains a public inner class ActivityFinisher which implements a Runnable.  The run method for that class is called before start of each test.  Here's what that code does:

```
public void run() {
  List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<>();

  for (Stage s : EnumSet.range(Stage.CREATED, Stage.STOPPED)) {
    activities.addAll(mLifecycleMonitor.getActivitiesInStage(s));
  }

  Log.i(TAG, "Activities that are still in CREATED to STOPPED: " + activities.size());

  for (Activity activity : activities) {
    if (!activity.isFinishing()) {
      try {
        Log.i(TAG, "Finishing activity: " + activity);
        activity.finish();
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to finish activity.", e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The call to activity.finish() is the culprit to why you get the message "No activities found".  The short of it is that AndroidJUnit4 is not implemented to do what you're trying to do. I can understand why you would like to do that, but the off-the-self AndroidJUnit4Runner doesn't work that way.

I've not investigated whether there is a easy way to work around this.  A simply thing you can do is to structure you test class to only contain one test.  Start the activity you want in an @Before method, and perform all your activity tests in that single @Test method.  This prevents the activity from being "finished" and "started" again for each test.  The other possible way to get around this would be to write your own custom runner class which might be a little more work than you want to do. I unfortunately don't know enough if that approach would actually work; or whether you would still run into the same issue.

I leave my answer as it is with an open question to others on whether there is a simply way to keep an android activity open over several tests.

Comment: annotation  "@Before" mean that every time before start every test will start  method annotate by "@Before". I don't need this.

Comment: You get the same problem if you do it in @BeforeClass or in a default constructor for the test class, I tried that.  The ActivityFinisher is called after every test and if I'm not mistaken before execution of the first test.  You just can't start an activity that will stay active over the span of multiple tests.